# How to use multiple pipelines while reindexing/creating an index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following [this link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-deploy-nlp-text-embeddings-and-vector-search) to try a semantic search in elastic search.
This tutorial uses just one text field for embedding, which worked for me. But now I want to try multiple fields for embedding, which ES-8.7 supports.

But the problem is when I try to reindex; I can give just one pipeline name which points to just one field. I created multiple pipelines for multiple fields. I do reindex to copy documents into new index with embedding.
Here is the code

```
embedding_pipeline_names = ["name_pipeline", "description_pipeline"]
embedding_pipeline_names = "name_pipeline" # works fine
elastic_search_client.reindex(
            source={"index": root_index_name},
            dest={
                "index": index_name_with_embedding,
                "pipeline": embedding_pipeline_names
            },
            wait_for_completion=False,
            requests_per_second=requests_per_second  # for batch request
            
        )
```

I get this error when I give an array in the pipeline key; it works fine if I give just one pipeline name.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', "[1:104] [dest] pipeline doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching the wrong way. I thought one pipeline could process just one field. That's why I was creating separate pipelines for each field.
But ES pipelines support multiple processors in the pipeline, which resolved the problem of having numerous pipelines during reindexing.